# Pay via PayPal Balance option not available in Sandbox Account

Tags: reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox, sandbox

Need your help.

I am configuring PayPal sandbox environment.
I have default Business & Personnel Sandbox Account for Australia Country.
I used CLIENT_ID from the default app created using Business Account.
I am using react.js to configure this.
In index.html file I put below script:

```js
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=my_client_id&currency=AUD&components=buttons,funding-eligibility"></script>
```

But when I try to login using my Personnel account, it doesn't show Payment option PayPal Balance.

[image]

**Please note: I am making this request from India**

Please see below code that I have configured

```
 useEffect(() => {

window.paypal
  .Buttons({
    createOrder: (data, actions, err) => {
      return actions.order.create({
        intent: "CAPTURE",
        purchase_units: [
          {
            description: "Cool looking table",
            amount: {
              currency_code: "AUD",
              value: 2.0,
            },
          },
        ],
      });
    },
    onApprove: async (data, actions) => {
      const order = await actions.order.capture();
      console.log(order);
    },
    onError: (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    },
    fundingSource:window.paypal.FUNDING.PAYPAL
  })
  .render(paypal.current);
```

}, []);

}

Answer (score 0):

PayPal India doesn't support wallet payments i.e. PayPal Balance.

Thanks.

Comment: I already have funds in my account (i.e. $6,000.00)

Comment: But my sandbox account is of Australia

Comment: Also, I tried using Australia VPN but no luck.